# "What if the cost of machines that think is people who don't?" -- George Dyson

Tags: expressions

What does the statement **"What if the cost of machines that think is people who don't?" -- George Dyson** mean.

Came across the quote over here https://twitter.com/JohnDCook/status/527627283256078336.

Comment: What would  the consequenses be if the price we pay for having 'intelligent' machines is having less 'intelligent' people  (people who think less)?

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks. But is the statement "The cost of machines that this is people who don't" grammatically correct. How did you grasp the meaning. It looks meaningless to me.

Comment: the cost  (of machines who think) is people who don't (think). Yes it is correct.

Comment: What if - http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv223.shtml

Comment: @Josh61: It's not necessarily a hypothetical (what would the consequences be...), it can also mean "have you ever considered the possibility that, in fact, .... is true?". And I'll suggest that in OP's sentence, it means precisely that: the author is not worried about a possible alternate reality, but about the possibility that it describes the *current* reality.

Comment: well..'have you ever considered the possibility that' intruduces an hypothesis..

Comment: What part of it troubles you? Analysing the overall semantics is litcrit, which may be off topic.

Comment: @Josh61: Hmm, I suppose I could have been clearer. Your wording above suggested it was counterfactual. I just said that it need not be counterfactual, but actually indicative, and that that is precisely the reading in the OP. "So, what if we did that?" can mean both "what do you think would be the result were we now to proceed in that way?" (we didn't do it yet, but we are considering it) as well as "what are you going to do if I tell you that we have actually already done it?" (we did do it, but I'm not going to admit it in so many words)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if the cost of machines that think is people who don't?

You may get confused with the different verbs popping up in this sentence, so let's see what happens if we change it a little bit.

Let's start with shaving off the *What if*. It means that we are wondering about something, but we can evaluate the statement we wonder about without the wondering:

> What if my cat is pregnant?

Is wondering about the statement:

> My cat is pregnant.

So we look at the statement:

> The cost of machines that think is people who don't.

Now, let's see. We have 4 things that may look like verbs (cost, think, is, don't).
The first one is a noun, let's replace it with a synonym so we don't get confused:

> The price of machines that think is people who don't.

*Think*, or rather *that think* is attributive to *machines*. Let's further reduce confusion and replace it with a simple adjective: *smart*.

> *The price of smart machines is people who don't. *(this sentence is incorrect)*

So, the price of X is Y. That is simple enough, but what does *people that don't* mean? We have just kicked *think* out of the sentence, but *people that don't* was short for *people that don't think*!

Now, in the same way we did for *that think*, we replace *that don't think* again with and adjective, let's use *stupid*:

> The price of smart machines is stupid people.

So, if you want smart machines, it means people will be stupid.
And the original sentence just wondered: what if this link exists? What if smart machines lead to stupid people?

No, one does not consciously go through all these steps to understand a sentence like this every time, but a similar process can happen subconsciously when trying to parse a sentence that does not immediately make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much. After reading your answer the statement "What if the cost of machines that think is people who don't?" makes complete sense.